# Implement dropzone in mvc razor form

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor, dropzone.js

I have a mvc form with multiple fields that are calling custom edit views. 
I need to implement dropzone instead of the standard file import control.
I cant figure out how to get the file names and pass them together with the dropzone. I am searching the internet for 2 days and no results.

The form looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("contr", "action", new { themeid = ViewBag.ThemeId, @class = "dropzone"}, FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

At the end I have an Edit view that contains the dropzone div:

```
<div id="fileInput" class="dropzone">
    <div class="fallback">
        <input name="files" type="file" multiple />
    </div>
</div>
```

Function for the dropzone:

```
function initDropzone() {
    new Dropzone('#fileInput', {
        url: '#',
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        autoDiscover: false,
        parallelUploads: 100,
        dictDefaultMessage: "Click or drop files to upload",
        init: function () {
            var myDropzone = this;
            $('#submit-all').click(function (e) {
                $(".dz-progress").show();

                myDropzone.processQueue();
            });
            myDropzone.on('success', function () {
                myDropzone.removeAllFiles();
                //$('#name').val('');
            });
            myDropzone.on("sending", function (file, xhr, formData) {
                formData.append("file", file); // Append all the additional input data of your form here!
            });
            myDropzone.on("addedfile", function (event) {
                $(".dz-progress").hide();

            });
        }

    });
```

As most examples suggest I call processQueue when submit is clicked, but the problem is that the controller action is called twice, once with the files but without the other models, and the next time with the models but without the files.

I can't use stopPropagation on submit because I call different views based on the logic in the action method.

The basic question is how I can take the files from dropzone and append them to form data. 
Hidden fields does not work, I don't know why.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your `#submit-all` button inside the form?

Comment: Yes it is inside, should i put it outside?

Comment: Then that button may be triggering the default form submission. In which case you should `.preventDefault()` or move it out so it won't  act as the form's submission button.

Comment: When i prevent default only the images are sent and not the rest of the form.